# JQuery page jumping to the top of the page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using this Jquery and it works great
The problem is when i click on the button the page jumps all the way to the top. I am using Miva if that makes a difference

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('.drop').click(function(){
            var $next = $(this).parent().next('li.drop_down');
            if($next.is(':visible')) {
                $next.slideUp();
            } else {
                $next.slideDown();
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try adding "return false" to the end of your click() function.

**Edit:** (adding code example)

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.drop').click(function(){
            var $next = $(this).parent().next('li.drop_down');
            if($next.is(':visible')) {
                $next.slideUp();
            } else {
                $next.slideDown();
            }

            return false;
        });
    });
```